# errors compiling project with boost asio

Tags: c++, compiler-errors, boost-asio

I have created a separate project to connect my server component to clients using TCP/IP with boost::asio.  I first created and tested this project separately first and tested these classes, everything worked fine.

Adding this to my server component it now no longer compiles and I get following compiler errors about code that is not even my code!

```
   c:\Program Files\boost\boost_1_44\boost\asio\detail\impl\win_iocp_io_service.ipp(442): error C2039: 'CreateWaitableTimer' : is not a member of 'operator``global namespace'''


    c:\Program Files\boost\boost_1_44\boost\asio\detail\impl\win_iocp_io_service.ipp(442): error C3861: 'CreateWaitableTimer': identifier not found, even with argument-dependent lookup
```

I have no idea why I am getting these errors, I have checked all include paths and all include files in the project.

Does anybody have any suggestions as to what can cause these errors?

The header file "tcp_server.h" is included in my project and is the one that causes the errors to pop up.  This is the class defined inside this file (written by myself)

```
#include "stdafx.h"

#include "tcp_connection.h" //boost shared_ptr etc included inside this file already
#include <ResolverQueueHandler.h> //Handles threaded queues for requests from client

class tcp_server
{
public:
    tcp_server::tcp_server(boost::asio::io_service& io_service, int port,boost::shared_ptr<ResolverQueueHandler> queue_handler);


private:

    void start_accept();
    void handle_accept(tcp_connection::pointer new_connection, const boost::system::error_code& error);

    boost::asio::io_service _io_service;
    boost::asio::ip::tcp::acceptor acceptor_;
    boost::shared_ptr<ResolverQueueHandler> _queue_handler;
    int _port;
};
```

Comment: check if boost_system and boost_regex libraries have been linked to

Comment: @ArunMu: How do I check that in VS2003? Are you talking about including them in my project? or just check the linker paths when compiling?

Comment: @ArunMu: These are compiler errors, not linker errors.

Comment: @Tony: hmmm...Visual studio...Windows..I never work on it :) .But see if the following link helps..not related to boost library..but still check if introducing the #define works or not. LINK : http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en/vcgeneral/thread/bcbac9af-feea-4150-bed7-e2428813f5b3

Comment: Is this header file(tcp_server.h) present with all other include files whose include path was given whicle compiling? If yes, try to include the boost related header files again in this header file.

Comment: post the rest of your headers `tcp_connection.h` and `ResolverQueueHandler.h` so we can try to compile them.

Comment: @ArunMuru, post that as an answer, cause that solved my problem, the #define did.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The Windows SDK activates various operating-system specific release's additional API calls by using Preprocessor `#define`s. This allows you to build applications for any version of Windows, while preventing you from inadvertently building an application that won't run on, say, Windows 98.

`::CreateWaitableTimer` was added at the same time Windows 2000 was released.  You'll need to add this `#define` to your applications - either in a common header, or in the project settings for the appropriate C++ project:

```
#define _WIN32_WINNT 0x0400
```

---

References:

CreateWaitableTimer: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms682492(v=vs.85).aspx

Using the Windows Headers:  http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa383745(v=vs.85).aspx

Answer (score 1):

Per [this](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en/vcgeneral/thread/bcbac9af-feea-4150-bed7-e2428813f5b3) thread you have to do a `#define` of  _WIN32_WINNT with right version number to avoid this error.